# Rails update_attributes without save?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

Is there an alternative to `update_attributes` that does not save the record?

So I could do something like:

```
@car = Car.new(:make => 'GMC')
#other processing
@car.update_attributes(:model => 'Sierra', :year => "2012", :looks => "Super Sexy, wanna make love to it")
#other processing
@car.save
```

BTW, I know I can `@car.model = 'Sierra'`, but I want to update them all on one line.

Comment: what do you mean "not save the record"?

Comment: update_attributes saves the model the DB. I'm wondering if there's a similar method that doesn't.

Comment: **attributes** non-destructive method. See [API](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#method-i-attributes-3D) for details

Comment: You can use update_column(name, value) Updates a single attribute of an object, without calling save. 1. Validation is skipped. 2. Callbacks are skipped. 3. updated_at/updated_on column is not updated if that column is available. http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Persistence/update_column

Comment: For 3.1+, use `assign_attributes` http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/assign_attributes

Answer (score 652, accepted):

I believe what you are looking for is [`assign_attributes`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/AttributeAssignment.html#method-i-assign_attributes).

It's basically the same as update_attributes but it doesn't save the record:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name
  attr_accessible :name, :is_admin, :as => :admin
end

user = User.new
user.assign_attributes({ :name => 'Josh', :is_admin => true }) # Raises an ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error
user.assign_attributes({ :name => 'Bob'})
user.name        # => "Bob"
user.is_admin?   # => false
user.new_record? # => true
```

Comment: Your example is a little bit misleading since you haven't pasted this line from the model: `attr_accessible :is_admin, :as => :admin` ;)

Comment: @Robin Or simply: `attr_protected :is_admin`. Or: `attr_accessible :name` The point being that in this example, :is_admin is protected. I should also note that attempting to mass assign a protected attribute with `.assign_attributes` does indeed raise an `ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error`, even though that isn't shown in the example.

Comment: Yeah but my line is from the doc you linked to. I'm just saying you should have copied/pasted the whole example. But yes, you can just say that it's protected.

Comment: @Robin I'll update the example to be a bit more specific. The example in the docs is also a bit misleading, as it doesn't mention that `user.assign_attributes({ :name => 'Josh', :is_admin => true })` raises an error message and doesn't actually set the user's name property.

Comment: You're right, it does throw an error... strange that they don't mention it.

Comment: assign_attributes is available from Rails 3.1 onwards, so you can't use it if you're still running an old version of Rails.

Comment: I have to look this up every time

Comment: @mr.musicman Yeah, that's actually why I initially wrote this answer. I found myself looking it up way too often, and the StackOverflow question about it didn't have `assign_attributes` as an answer.

Comment: i am using assign attributes but getting a problem. i have a model templates that have many stages(nested model). when i can assign_attributes on templates, it save nested stages which is causing problem for me.

Answer (score 208):

You can use `assign_attributes` or `attributes=` (they're the same)

**Update methods cheat sheet (for Rails 6):**

- `update` = `assign_attributes` + `save`
- `attributes=` = alias of `assign_attributes`
- `update_attributes` = deprecated, alias of `update`

**Source:**
https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/persistence.rb
https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb

**Another cheat sheet:**
http://www.davidverhasselt.com/set-attributes-in-activerecord/#cheat-sheet

Comment: in case of .attributes = val, if your model has_one and accepts_nested_attributes_for another model, passing that_model_attributes (without id) will delete the existing has_one model, even if you didn't persist (e.g. save). But assign_attributes doesn't behave like that.

Answer (score 68):

You can use the 'attributes' method:

```
@car.attributes = {:model => 'Sierra', :years => '1990', :looks => 'Sexy'}
```

Source: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html

**attributes=(new_attributes, guard_protected_attributes = true)**
Allows you to set all the attributes at once by passing in a hash with keys matching the attribute names (which again matches the column names).

If guard_protected_attributes is true (the default), then sensitive attributes can be protected from this form of mass-assignment by using the attr_protected macro. Or you can alternatively specify which attributes can be accessed with the attr_accessible macro. Then all the attributes not included in that won’t be allowed to be mass-assigned.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_protected :is_admin
end

user = User.new
user.attributes = { :username => 'Phusion', :is_admin => true }
user.username   # => "Phusion"
user.is_admin?  # => false

user.send(:attributes=, { :username => 'Phusion', :is_admin => true }, false)
user.is_admin?  # => true
```

Answer (score 9):

For mass assignment of values to an ActiveRecord model without saving, use either the `assign_attributes` or `attributes=` methods.  These methods are available in Rails 3 and newer.  However, there are minor differences and version-related gotchas to be aware of.

Both methods follow this usage:

```
@user.assign_attributes{ model: "Sierra", year: "2012", looks: "Sexy" }

@user.attributes = { model: "Sierra", year: "2012", looks: "Sexy" }
```

Note that neither method will perform validations or execute callbacks; callbacks and validation will happen when `save` is called.

## Rails 3

`attributes=` differs slightly from `assign_attributes` in Rails 3.  `attributes=` will check that the argument passed to it is a Hash, and returns immediately if it is not; `assign_attributes` has no such Hash check.  See the [ActiveRecord Attribute Assignment API documentation for `attributes=`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.1/classes/ActiveRecord/AttributeAssignment.html#method-i-attributes-3D).

The following invalid code will silently fail by simply returning without setting the attributes:

```
@user.attributes = [ { model: "Sierra" }, { year: "2012" }, { looks: "Sexy" } ]
```

`attributes=` will silently behave as though the assignments were made successfully, when really, they were not.

This invalid code will raise an exception when `assign_attributes` tries to stringify the hash keys of the enclosing array:

```
@user.assign_attributes([ { model: "Sierra" }, { year: "2012" }, { looks: "Sexy" } ])
```

`assign_attributes` will raise a `NoMethodError` exception for `stringify_keys`, indicating that the first argument is not a Hash.  The exception itself is not very informative about the actual cause, but the fact that an exception does occur is *very* important.

The only difference between these cases is the method used for mass assignment: `attributes=` silently succeeds, and `assign_attributes` raises an exception to inform that an error has occurred.

These examples may seem contrived, and they are to a degree, but this type of error can easily occur when converting data from an API, or even just using a series of data transformation and forgetting to `Hash[]` the results of the final `.map`.  Maintain some code 50 lines above and 3 functions removed from your attribute assignment, and you've got a recipe for failure.

The lesson with Rails 3 is this: *always* use `assign_attributes` instead of `attributes=`.

## Rails 4

In Rails 4, `attributes=` is simply an alias to `assign_attributes`.  See the [ActiveRecord Attribute Assignment API documentation for `attributes=`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AttributeAssignment.html).

With Rails 4, either method may be used interchangeably.  Failure to pass a Hash as the first argument will result in a very helpful exception: `ArgumentError: When assigning attributes, you must pass a hash as an argument.`

## Validations

If you're pre-flighting assignments in preparation to a `save`, you might be interested in validating before save, as well.  You can use the `valid?` and `invalid?` methods for this.  Both return boolean values.  `valid?` returns true if the unsaved model passes all validations or false if it does not.  `invalid?` is simply the inverse of `valid?`

`valid?` can be used like this:

```
@user.assign_attributes{ model: "Sierra", year: "2012", looks: "Sexy" }.valid?
```

This will give you the ability to handle any validations issues in advance of calling `save`.