# _changed? in rails 3.1.0 app did not work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Here is the code for update in invoice controller:

```
  def update
      @invoice = Invoice.find(params[:id])
      if @invoice.approved_by_corp_head_changed?
        @invoice.approve_date_corp_head = Time.now
        @invoice.corp_head_id = session[:user_id]
      end
      if @invoice.update_attributes(params[:invoice], :as => :roles_update)
        redirect_to URI.escape("/view_handler?index=0&msg=Updated")
      else
        flash.now[:error] = 'Not saved！'
        render 'edit'
      end
  end
```

Value of approved_by_corp_head was saved correctly. The problem is that `if @invoice.approved_by_corp_head_changed?` was always false and the IF loop never gets executed. In rails console, the @invoice.approved_by_corp_head_changed? is true if the value is changed. What could be wrong here? Thanks so much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you fetch an object directly from the database, it's brand new, so there is no reason it could be changed somehow.

Moreover, `_changed?` is available until the object is actually saved.

One option would be to get the changes from the `params` but not update your object directly. This issue [has been discussed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6770350/rails-update-attributes-without-save).

Sidenote: why do you do:

```
redirect_to URI.escape("/view_handler?index=0&msg=Updated")
```

instead of:

```
redirect_to path_name_path(:index => 0, :msg => "Updated")
```

Comment: Thanks. I was wondering if the @invoice was changed before calling update_attributes. view_handler is a custom method to keep the viewing history. The Back in rails will form a loop after edit or create.