# How to set a dynamic attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, dynamic-attributes

Is there a way to set ***col*** as dynamic or convert it in some way to a valid attribute?
It is currently throwing the error: undefined method `col=' for #...

```
def copy_stock_data_from_sandbox(cntrlr)
  source_table = cntrlr.singularize.classify.constantize
  dest_table = source_table.new
  source_table.column_names.each do |col|
    dest_table.col = xyz    # <------ This is the line in question
  end
  dest_table.save
end
```

Also, not sure if the title is accurate, please suggest if 'dynamic attribute' is the wrong term for this situation. Thanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I believe that you're looking for the following:

```
dest_table.send(:"#{col}=", xyz)
```

Answer (score 13):

You can try

```
dest_table.write_attribute(col, xyz)
```

OR

```
dest_table[col] = xyz
```

OR

```
dest_table.send("#{col}=", xyz)
```

Comment: `write_attribute` is a private method

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a more idiomatic Rails solution would be to use

[`assign_attributes`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/AttributeAssignment.html#method-i-assign_attributes) or `attributes=`(which is an alias of `assign_attributes`).

```rb
attrs = User.column_names.each_with_object({}) do |col, hash|
  hash[col] = xyz
end

dest_table.assign_attributes attrs
```

Also, related question:

[Rails update_attributes without save?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6770350/rails-update-attributes-without-save)