# Is there a way to mass assign an existing record without saving?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

I have a `ProductsColor` model. Given a params hash, is there a way to set an existing record's attributes with one method without saving it? Similar to how `ProductsColor.new(params)` would instantiate an object and set its attribute to the ones in the `params` hash, I want to set attributes of an existing record without saving it like so:

```
    params = {name: "hey"}

    p = ProductsColor.find(1)
    p.something(params) # does not save to the database, but does set the value of the params to p in memory
    p.name # "hey"
    p.save # <-- now it saves permanently
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```
p = ProductsColor.find(1)
p.assign_attributes(params)
```

It will not be saved

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is:

> assign_attributes

which will update the attributes without saving the record.

Check this answer for more info:

[Rails update_attributes without save?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6770350/rails-update-attributes-without-save)

Answer (score 0):

There is a active record method called assign_attributes to assign the attributes for active record object. It should be something like below,

```
products_color = ProductsColor.first
products_color.assign_attributes({name: 'New name'})
```